# Connection object is not null in contructor i which i invoked to get connection object but in other function to use cbject i am getting null

Tags: java, object

`Connection` object is not null in the constructor which i invoked to get connection object  but in other function to use object I am getting null.

```
package shoppings;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;`
import Filehandling.MyConnection;

public class Product {

    public static void main( String args[]){
        String sql = "select ProductID, ProductName from products ";
        ProductDetail ub = new ProductDetail(  );
        ub.getProductDetail();
    }
}

    class ProductDetail{
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    public ProductDetail(){
        MyConnection mycon = new MyConnection();
         Connection con = mycon.getConnObject("");
         System.out.println(con);
         //o/t com.mysql.jdbc.Connection@7cca494b
    }

    public void getProductDetail( ){

         System.out.println(con);
        //o/t null

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the variable in your constructor to the instance variable. Try this:

```
public ProductDetail(){
     MyConnection mycon = new MyConnection();
     con = mycon.getConnObject("");
     System.out.println(con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, your connection object here:

```
public ProductDetail(){
    MyConnection mycon = new MyConnection();
     Connection con = mycon.getConnObject("");
     System.out.println(con);
}
```

is locally scoped to the method ProductDetails and will no longer be avaliable after that method is done, so it is making shadow over the class connection member

do instead:

```
 public ProductDetail(){
     MyConnection mycon = new MyConnection();
     con = mycon.getConnObject("");
     System.out.println(con);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you declare a `Connection con` local variable and you instantiate it :

```
public ProductDetail(){
       ...
     Connection con = mycon.getConnObject("");
       ...
 }
```

But this local variable is a distinct variable from the `Connection con` variable field declared here :

```
class ProductDetail{
 ....
    Connection con=null;
}
```

So assigning one of them doesn't change the value of the other one.

If you want to value the `Connection con` field, you don't need to declare another variable in the constructor.
Just change your constructor to assign the new created `Connection` to the instance field :

```
con = new MyConnection().getConnObject("");
```